# Is Java a "completely" object-oriented language?

Tags: java, object

Recently at a job interview I was asked "Is Java a "completely" object-oriented language?"

As I was completely unable to answer that question and do not know the answer, could someone, please, help me to understand the nature of this question.

As I see the question is being closed as "opinion-based" that's not an opinion I'm asking. I'm asking if I am unaware of that  completely/incompletely category.

Kindly tell me if that's a wrong forum to ask this.

Comment: This is 100% personal opinion but I try to avoid working for any company that asks questions like that in an interview.

Comment: Was this asked by HR or actual dev manager?

Comment: I'm not sure what the interviewer actually meant but as far as pure Java is concerned I'd say: yes it is completely object oriented, since everything is built around the notion of a class/object. There are no free functions like in C/C++ etc. If you throw other JVM language into the mix it's a completely different story.

Comment: @Aeseir By a developer that's why I'm asking here

Comment: @Thomas Yes, but because there are primitive values too, you could just as easily argue that it isn't "completely" OOP. And this is why the question doesn't make sense (which is not OP's fault of course) and is opinion-based.

Comment: Try to invoke some method on an `int` literal - clearly an `int` behaves very different than a "real" object.

Comment: @Alex thanks mate, just clarifying.

Comment: @biziclop yes, that could be the case. Additionally with Java 8's lambdas you could also argue that there's a functional component in Java, so it's not completely object oriented any more - even if you'd accept the primitives as a basic requirement of an OO language

Comment: @biziclop - i don't think this is a bad interview question, as it checks if the candidate has some background knowledge on OO paradigms (one might compare Java to say Smalltalk or Scala)

Comment: @Thomas To make matters worse though, lambdas behave like objects.

Comment: @GyroGearless The way this one is phrased makes it sound like extreme nit-picking and referring to some unknown authority. If the question was "Would you describe Java as a completely OOP language, and why?", it would be a good question, where whether you answer yes or no is not as important as how you justify your answer.

Comment: @Thomas Static methods are pretty much your "free functions".

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik that would be a debatable topic :) They can be used like this but still operate in the context of a class.

Comment: @Thomas No, they don't actually. All the class provides is a namespace. They are top-level, global functions, accessible outside of any object context. No objects *at all* need to exist in a JVM to call a static method.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Hmm, what about the `Class` object which the static method operates on? The scope of static methods would still depend on the classloader the class is associated with, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Thomas No `Class` objects are associated with executing a static method unless the method is `synchronized`, and even in that case the `Class` object is treated in a completely non-OOP way: only its monitor is involved. The classloader is just a mechanism for loading modules in this case.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you have a point here :)

Comment: Btw, as a final comment, here's an interesting "progammers" question on that topic: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/164570/formal-definition-for-term-pure-oo-language

Answer (score 3):

Java has primitives. Primitives are not Objects.

Comment: java supports wrapper class so int , long , etc are the object of the wrapper class.
so how can you call java is not pure object oriented

Comment: @Veke It would only have the wrapper classes if it were.

Comment: So can we say because of primitive data types Java is not pure object oriented?

Comment: It also has static members.

Comment: One should not mix and mash the context; the question is if the Java -language- follows the exact definition of being an OO language. No it is not, for the simple reasons mentioned here and on dozens upon dozens of other sources on the net. The fact that the standard API offers some wrapper classes does not change any facts about the language.

Comment: anyway it is possible to write a 100% object oriented code

Answer (score 2):

No. Java is not because it supports Primitive datatype[^] such as int, byte, long... etc, to be used, which are not objects.

There are seven qualities to be satisfied for a programming language to be pure Object Oriented. They are:

- Encapsulation/Data Hiding
- Inheritance
- Polymorphism
- Abstraction
- All predefined types are objects
- All operations are performed by sending messages to objects
- All user defined types are objects

Comment: where do these 7 qualities come from?

Comment: Ask a LISPer what qualities need to be satisfied and you'll hear a completely different story. OOP is primarily about dynamic method dispatch. In your list that roughly corresponds to polymorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you look at it, but yes, as @biziclop said, it's a matter of opinion.

To break it down, Java is, as you know, an object oriented language, but it's still possible to do functional programming in it (a static method that takes a primitive argument and returns a result).

Since primitives are not objects you can do non-object programming with Java.

So technically, no, Java is not a completely object-oriented language.

Answer (score 1):

well Java is not 100% object oriented, because it still contains *Primitive datatype*

for example:

```
int i=0;
```

here `i` is not an object but contains the actual value.

However,

```
Set<String> set=new HashSet<String>();
```

`set` is a refrence that referes to a HashSet

Comment: Java does not have pointers, `set` is a reference.

Comment: @rpattiso Sorry mate, I used wrong terminology here, but in reality pointer is basically a reference. I've changed pointer to reference in my answer